# Pairwise swap elements of a given linked list (Java solution)

Tags: java, linked-list

I want to solve the following task:

> Given a singly linked list, write a function to swap elements
>   pairwise. For example, if the linked list is 1->2->3->4->5->6->7 then
>   the function should change it to 2->1->4->3->6->5->7, and if the
>   linked list is 1->2->3->4->5->6 then the function should change it to
>   2->1->4->3->6->5

To do so, I use recursive approach taken from here: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pairwise-swap-elements-of-a-given-linked-list-by-changing-links/ , namely, swap the first two nodes, and then recurse on the rest of the list. My function is the following:

```
 private static ListNode reorder(ListNode l1) {
        if(l1 == null || l1.next == null)
            return l1;
        ListNode rest = l1.next.next;
        //change head
        ListNode newHead = l1.next;
        //change next of second node
        newHead.next = l1;
        l1.next = reorder(rest);
        return newHead;
    }
```

However on the input 1 2 3 4 5 6  I have output 1 4 3 6 5?! I debugged it but still can't see where is the problem. Can anyone explain me why this is the case? Here is the whole class:

```
public class Swap {

    public static class ListNode {
          int val;
          ListNode next;
          ListNode(int x) {
              val = x;
              next = null;
          }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ListNode l1 = new ListNode(1);
        ListNode l2 = new ListNode(2);
        ListNode l3 = new ListNode(3);
        ListNode l4 = new ListNode(4);
        ListNode l5 = new ListNode(5);
        ListNode l6 = new ListNode(6);
        ListNode l7 = new ListNode(7);
        ListNode l8 = new ListNode(8);
        ListNode l9 = new ListNode(9);
        ListNode l10 = new ListNode(10);
        l1.next = l2;
        l2.next = l3;
        l3.next = l4;
        l4.next = l5;
        l5.next = l6; 
        l7.next = l8;
        l9.next = l10;
        print(l1);
        reorder(l1);
        System.out.println();
        print(l1);

    }
    private static void print(ListNode l1) {
        ListNode current = l1;
        while(current != null){
            System.out.print(current.val + " ");
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
    private static ListNode reorder(ListNode l1) {
        if(l1 == null || l1.next == null)
            return l1;
        ListNode rest = l1.next.next;
        //change head
        ListNode newHead = l1.next;
        //change next of second node
        newHead.next = l1;
        l1.next = reorder(rest);
        return newHead;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you need a recursive solution?  _" I debugged it but still can't see where is the problem"_ -- sorry, if you actually traced through the code you should be able to provide more details on what you don't understand.

Comment: @JimGarrison Recursive solution is easier - swap the first two nedes and recurse on the rest. It can be written iteratively also, but first I want to understand where is my mistake with the recursive approach.

Comment: You're going to be potentially unhappy when you get support calls about excessive memory usage from your clients when the list contains a few hundred-thousand entries.  The iterative solution takes almost no extra memory and will probably run faster as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're printing the list starting at l1, which is now the second element. You want to call

```
print(reorder(l1));
```

Comment: Thanks. To excuse myself, now it is 3:30 AM at my time zone :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a recursive approach I did, it works for me. Let me know if there is any problem.

```
public void pairwiseSwap(Node node){
    if(size() == 0){
        System.out.println("empty");
        return;
    }
    if(node.next == null){
        System.out.println(node.value);
        return;
    }
    Node one = node;
    Node two = node.next;
    System.out.println(two.value);
    System.out.println(one.value);
    if(two.next == null)
        return;
    pairwiseSwap(two.next);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works, for me. I already accepted another answer, so O just up-voted yours. If you liked my question, can you up-voted the question?

Answer (score 0):

your list is not well connected, you are missing these links:

```
    l6.next = l7;
    l8.next = l9;
```

Comment: Thanks, I didnt notice that. However now on the input 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 I have output 1 4 3 6 5 8 7 10 9 (still the same)

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the solution for most f the linked list replated problems**

1. Insert at Start
2. Insert at End
3. Insert at Position
4. Get the size of the list
5. Display the list
6. Delete from the list
7. Replace the node
8. Search item position in the list
9. Find the middle of the list"
10. Get the item from the last
11. Reverse the list
12. Swap the node of the list
13. Pairwise swap the list
14. Make the last node as the first node

**Node.java**

```
package com.practice.ds.list;

final public class Node<T> {

    public Node<T> next = null;
    public Node<T> prev = null;
    public T data = null;

    public Node() {

    }

    public Node(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Node [next=" + next + ", prev=" + prev + ", data=" + data + "]";
    }

}
```

**LinkedList.java**

```
package com.practice.ds.list;

public class LinkedList<T> {

    private Node<T> head = null;
    private Node<T> tail = null;

    public void insertAtStart(T data) {
        throwEmptyDataException(data);
        Node<T> node = new Node<T>(data);
        if(empty()) {
            head = node;
            tail = head;
        }else {
            node.next = head;
            head = node;
        }
        display();
    }

    public void insertAtEnd(T data) {
        throwEmptyDataException(data);
        if(empty()) {
            insertAtStart(data);
        }else {
            Node<T> node = new Node<T>(data);
            tail.next = node;
            tail = node;
            display();
        }
    }

    public void insertAtPosition(int position, T data) {
        throwEmptyDataException(data);
        if (position < 1 || position > size() || empty())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't perform insertion. Please check your inputs");
        Node<T> node = head;
        Node<T> tempNode = node;
        for (int i = 1; i <= size(); i++) {
            if (i == position) {
                if (node == head) {
                    insertAtStart(data);
                    return;
                } else {
                    Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>(data);
                    tempNode.next = newNode;
                    newNode.next = node;
                    display();
                    break;
                }
            }
            tempNode = node;
            node = node.next;
        }
    }

    public boolean delete(int position) {
        if (empty() || position < 1 || position > size())
            return false;
        Node<T> node = head;
        Node<T> tempNode = node;
        for (int i = 1; i <= size(); i++) {
            if(i == position) {
                if(node == head) {
                    head = head.next;
                    return true;
                }else if(node == tail) {
                    tempNode.next = null;
                    tail = tempNode;
                    return true;
                }else {
                    tempNode.next = node.next;
                    return true;
                }
            }
            tempNode = node;
            node = node.next;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public T replace(int position, T data) {
        throwEmptyDataException(data);
        if (empty() || position < 1 || position > size())
            return null;

        Node<T> node = head;
        for (int i = 1; i <= size(); i++) {
            if(i == position) {
                T replaceData = node.data;
                node.data = data;
                return replaceData;
            }
            node = node.next;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public boolean search(T data) {
        Node<T> node = head;
        while(node != null && !node.data.equals(data)) {
            node = node.next;
        }
        return node != null;
    }

    public T middle() {
        Node<T> slowPtr = head;
        Node<T> fastPtr = head;
        while(fastPtr != null && fastPtr.next != null) {
            slowPtr = slowPtr.next;
            fastPtr = fastPtr.next.next;
        }
        return empty() ? null : slowPtr.data;
    }

    public T getElementFromLast(int position) {
        if(empty() || position < 1 || position > getSizeIteratively())
            return null;
        Node<T> firstPtr = head;
        Node<T> secondPtr = head;
        for(int i = 1;i<=size();i++) {
            if(i > position)
                firstPtr = firstPtr.next;
            if(secondPtr.next == null)
                return firstPtr.data;
            secondPtr = secondPtr.next;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void reverse() {
        Node<T> prev = null;
        Node<T> current = head;
        Node<T> next = null;
        while(current != null) {
            next = current.next;
            current.next = prev;
            prev = current;
            current = next;
        }
        swapHeadTail();
        displayIteratively();
    }


    public void reverseRecursively() {
        reverseRecursively(head);
        swapHeadTail();
        display();
    }

    private Node<T> reverseRecursively(Node<T> node) {
        if(node == null || node.next == null)
            return node;
        Node<T> secondNode = node.next;
        node.next = null;
        Node<T> reverseRest = reverseRecursively(secondNode);
        secondNode.next = node;
        return reverseRest;
    }

    private void swapHeadTail() {
        Node<T> temp = head;
        head = tail;
        tail = temp;
    }

    public void swapPairwise() {
        if(empty())
            return;
        Node<T> firstNode = head;
        Node<T> secondNode = firstNode.next;
        while(firstNode != null && secondNode != null) {
            swap(firstNode.data, secondNode.data);
            firstNode = firstNode.next;
            if(firstNode != null)
                secondNode = firstNode.next;
        }
    }

    public void swap(T firstData, T secondData) {
        throwEmptyException();
        throwEmptyDataException(firstData);
        throwEmptyDataException(secondData);

        if(firstData.equals(secondData))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(firstData +" & "+ secondData+" both are the same. Can't swap");

        Node<T> firstDataPtr = head;
        Node<T> prevfirstDataPtr = firstDataPtr;

        while (firstDataPtr != null && !firstDataPtr.data.equals(firstData)) {
            prevfirstDataPtr = firstDataPtr;
            firstDataPtr = firstDataPtr.next;
        }

        Node<T> secondDataPtr = head;
        Node<T> prevSecondDataPtr = secondDataPtr;

        while (secondDataPtr!= null && !secondDataPtr.data.equals(secondData)) {
            prevSecondDataPtr = secondDataPtr;
            secondDataPtr = secondDataPtr.next;
        }

        if(!(firstDataPtr == null || secondDataPtr == null)) {

            // either first node or second node is head node
            if (firstDataPtr == head)
                head = secondDataPtr;
            else if (secondDataPtr == head)
                head = firstDataPtr;

            // either first node or second node is tail node
            if (firstDataPtr == tail)
                tail = secondDataPtr;
            else if (secondDataPtr == tail)
                tail = firstDataPtr;

            // getting the next pointer of both nodes
            Node<T> nextFirstDataPtr = firstDataPtr.next;
            Node<T> nextSecondDataPtr = secondDataPtr.next;

            // swapping the nodes
            prevfirstDataPtr.next = secondDataPtr;
            secondDataPtr.next = nextFirstDataPtr;
            prevSecondDataPtr.next = firstDataPtr;
            firstDataPtr.next = nextSecondDataPtr;

            // checking if both node is adjacent node
            // if both nodes are adjacent re-adjust the pointer
            if(nextFirstDataPtr == secondDataPtr) {
                secondDataPtr.next = firstDataPtr;
            } else if(nextSecondDataPtr == firstDataPtr) {
                firstDataPtr.next = secondDataPtr;
            }

        } else 
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Either "+firstData+" or "+secondData+" not present in the list");
        displayIteratively();
    }

    public void setLastNodeAsFirstNode() {
        if(empty() || head.next == null) {
            return;         
        }
        Node<T> node = head;
        Node<T> prevNode = node;
        while (node.next != null) {
            prevNode = node;
            node = node.next;
        }
        node.next = head;
        head = node;
        prevNode.next = null;
        tail = prevNode;
        display();
    }

    public int getSizeIteratively() {
        if (empty())
            return 0;
        int size = 0;
        Node<T> node = head;
        while (node != null) {
            ++size;
            node = node.next;
        }
        return size;
    }

    public int size() {
        return size(head, 0);
    }

    private int size(Node<T> node, int size) {
        return node != null ? size(node.next, ++size) : size;
    }

    public void displayIteratively() {
        Node<T> node = head;
        while (node != null) {
            System.out.print(node.data + " ");
            node = node.next;
        }
    }

    public void display() {
        display(head);
    }

    private void display(Node<T> node) {
        if (node != null) {
            System.out.print(node.data + " ");
            display(node.next);
        }
    }

    public void throwEmptyException() {
        if (empty())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("List is empty!");
    }

    private void throwEmptyDataException(T data) {
        if (data == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("data is null !");
    }

    public boolean empty() {
        return head == null;
    }
}
```

**LinkedListTest.java**

```
package com.practice.ds.list;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class LinkedListTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
        boolean exit = false;
        do {
            System.out.println("\n----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("1. Insert at Start");
            System.out.println("2. Insert at End");
            System.out.println("3. Insert at Position");
            System.out.println("4. Get the size of list");
            System.out.println("5. Display the list");
            System.out.println("6. Delete from the list ");
            System.out.println("7. Replace the node ");
            System.out.println("8. Search item position in the list ");
            System.out.println("9. Find the middle of the list");
            System.out.println("10. Get item from the last : ");
            System.out.println("11. Reverse the list :: ");
            System.out.println("12. Swap the node of the list");
            System.out.println("13. Pairwise swap the list");
            System.out.println("14. Make last node as first node");
            System.out.println("15. Segregate even and odd node");
            System.out.println();
            int choice = scanner.nextInt();
            switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                try {
                    System.out.println("Insert the node : ");
                    int node = scanner.nextInt();
                    list.insertAtStart(node);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;

            case 2:
                try {
                    System.out.println("Insert the node : ");
                    int node = scanner.nextInt();
                    list.insertAtEnd(node);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;

            case 3:
                try {
                    System.out.println("Enter the position :");
                    int position = scanner.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Insert the node :");
                    int node = scanner.nextInt();
                    list.insertAtPosition(position, node);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;

            case 4:
                try {
                    System.out.println("Getting the size :: ");
                    System.out.println("1. Get Iteratively");
                    System.out.println("2. Get Recursively");
                    int input = scanner.nextInt();
                    switch (input) {
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("The size of the list :: " + list.getSizeIteratively());
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        System.out.println("The size of the list :: " + list.size());
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Invalid input...!");
                        break;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;

            case 5:
                try {
                    System.out.println("Displaying the list :: ");
                    System.out.println("1. Display Iteratively");
                    System.out.println("2. Display Recursively");
                    int input = scanner.nextInt();
                    switch (input) {
                    case 1:
                        list.displayIteratively();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        list.display();
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Invalid input...!");
                        break;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;

            case 6:
                try {
                    System.out.println("Enter the position ");
                    int position = scanner.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("is Delete :: " + list.delete(position));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;

            case 7:
                try {
                    System.out.println("Enter the position ");
                    int position = scanner.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Insert the item ");
                    int data = scanner.nextInt();
                    list.replace(position, data);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;

            case 8:
                try {
                    System.out.println("Note: It will give first occurence of the item ");
                    System.out.println("Enter the item ");
                    int data = scanner.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(list.search(data));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;

            case 9:
                try {
                    System.out.println("The Middle node of the list is :: " + list.middle());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;

            case 10:
                System.out.println("Enter the position ");
                try {
                    int position = scanner.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Element is :: " + list.getElementFromLast(position));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;

            case 11:
                System.out.println("Reversing the list...");
                System.out.println("1. Iteratively");
                System.out.println("2. Recursively");
                int key = scanner.nextInt();
                switch (key) {
                case 1:
                    try {
                        list.reverse();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;

                case 2:
                    try {
                        list.reverseRecursively();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("Your choice is out of the box...! \ntry again...");
                    break;
                }
                break;

            case 12:
                try {
                    System.out.println("Enter first node ");
                    int firstNode = scanner.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Enter second node ");
                    int secondNode = scanner.nextInt();
                    list.swap(firstNode, secondNode);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;

            case 13:
                try {
                    list.swapPairwise();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;

            case 14:
                try {
                    list.setLastNodeAsFirstNode();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Your choice is out of the box...! \ntry again...");
                break;
            }
        } while (!exit);
        scanner.close();
    }

}
```